# GA4: One or two streams for landing and web app

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

We got a landing page where users get information's about our product and as a subdomain a wep app. We are also having apps for iOS and Android as well.
The question is, do we need two web streams in GA4, one for the landing page and one for the web app? Or should we use the same config for both products? Technically they are routed to completely different sources.

Best regards.